# how to access JSON data and display it in XCode Logcat and if response is null i want to show alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, asp.net-web-api

Below is the sample code that getting data from Web and am try to show it in logcat. I pst code here. Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance

```
NSArray *dicAllNetworks = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSLog(@"JsonData=%@",dicAllNetworks);

for (NSDictionary *dict in dicAllNetworks)
{
    NSInteger number = [dict[@"UserID"] intValue];
    NSString *UserTypeConst =dict[@"UserTypeConst"];
    NSString *name = dict[@"UserName"];
}
```

Here is response :

```
JsonData=[{"UserID":2478,"UserTypeConst":"PQR","UserName":"115005p"}]
```

if response is null

i want to show alert.

Comment: You're accessing the data in for loop what else you want?

Comment: when debugger goes in for loop ...it give me Terminating app due to uncaught exception@inder

Comment: At which point it's giving such error, also post the whole exception log

Comment: JsonData=[{"UserID":2478,"UserTypeConst":"PQR","UserName":"115005p"}]   
2017-03-03 12:14:12.460 api[11500:120541] -[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800005dee0         
2017-03-03 12:14:12.534 api[11500:120541] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800005dee0'

Comment: How is your `data` formed?

Comment: in JSON format@inder

Comment: I mean how you're creating this object?

Comment: I don't know what is causing the issue but your `dicAllNetworks` is `NSString` instead of `NSArray`

Comment: First of all if you are able to control the type of data `JsonData=[{"UserID":2478,"UserTypeConst":"PQR","UserName":"115005p"}]` do in source code and convert user id to string. Then your JSON data will return  `"UserID": "2478"` and all will be done.

Comment: i try this also again it give ....terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException@inder

Comment: if i comment then also give terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException @Nazir

Comment: @SagarRathod can you `NSLog(@"JsonData=%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` and post the output

Comment: I got your error `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count` you are trying to enumerate string

Comment: 2017-03-03 13:07:38.507 api[15117:154818] data is:<225b7b5c 22557365 7249445c 223a3234 2c5c2255 73657254 79706543 6f6e7374 5c223a5c 22504152 5c222c5c 22557365 724e616d 655c223a 5c223136 30303035 705c227d 5d22> @inder

Comment: The problem is that `dicAllNetworks` is not an `Array`

Comment: @SagarRathod could you past here NSLog(@"JsonData=%@",dicAllNetworks)

Comment: @Nazir it's already posted in the question

Comment: using this NSLog(@"JsonData=%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);    we get.....    JsonData="[{\"UserID\":24,\"UserTypeConst\":\"PAR\",\"UserName\":\"160005p\"}]"   @inder kumar

Comment: JsonData=[{"UserID":2478,"UserTypeConst":"PQR","UserName":"1‌​15005p"}] @Nazir

Comment: try this with other option `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

```
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                                UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please enter valid UserID and Password" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                                                UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                                     {
                                                                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                                     }];

                                                [alert addAction:ok];
                                                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                                                NSLog(@"Invalide Login Credential.");


                                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dicAllNetworks)
{
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:dict[@"UserID"]];
    NSString *UserTypeConst =dict[@"UserTypeConst"];
    NSString *name = dict[@"UserName"];
}
```

Comment: NSNumber *number = [dict[@"UserID"]]; after first closing square bracket it show red mark

Comment: check updated answer

Try NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:dict[@"UserID"]];

Comment: its give me the error, expected identifier required in your code@jignesh

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dicAllNetworks){
    NSInteger number = [[dict valueForKey:@"UserID"] integerValue];
    NSString *UserTypeConst =[dict valueForKey:@"UserTypeConst"];
    NSString *name = [dict valueForKey:@"userName"];
}
```

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `data` please see the code below and read the comments

```
//This is your actual string
// Code 1
// NSString *jstr = @"\"[{\\\"UserID\\\":24,\\\"UserTypeConst\\\":\\\"PAR\\\",\\\"UserNa‌​me\\\":\\\"160005p\\\"}]\"";

// where as your string be like this
// Code 2
NSString *jstr = @"[{\"UserID\":2478,\"UserTypeConst\":\"PQR\",\"UserName\":\"115005p\"}]";
NSData *data = [jstr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



NSArray *dicAllNetworks = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSLog(@"JsonData=%@",dicAllNetworks);

for (NSDictionary *dict in dicAllNetworks)
{
  NSInteger number = [dict[@"UserID"] intValue];
  NSString *UserTypeConst =dict[@"UserTypeConst"];
  NSString *name = dict[@"UserName"];
}
```

Just Run the above sample it will work fine, but when you comment `Code 2` and uncomment `Code 1` you get your problem. 
 I don't know how you're create your `data` object but that's not a valid json.

---

In your existing code just change the code as below

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *dicAllNetworks = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"eror=%@", error);
```

You can see that your json is malformed

Comment: hi inder its working thankyou i m trying to solve this pervious 5 hours thank you so much@inder kumar rathore